# Webpack remove snippet code after build, how to keep it?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I defined a snippet code and show it in web so users can copy to use  but after build app with Webpack production mode the snippet gone.

I think that webpack treat it like unused code so it be removed when build.

Snippet code:

```js
let html = `
      <script>
        (function(w, d, t, s, n) {
          ...
          const fn = function() {
            (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments);
          };
          w[n] = w[n] || fn;
          const f = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
          const e = d.createElement(t);
          const h = '?v' + new Date().getTime();
          e.async = true;
          e.src = s + h;
          f.parentNode.insertBefore(e, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', '${process.env.UNIVERSAL_SCRIPT}', 'fd');
        window.fd('form', { userId: '${form.userId}', formId: '${form.id}' });
      </script>
    `;
    html = jsBeautify.html(html, { indent_size: 2 });
```

Render in react component:

```js
<SyntaxHighlighter language="xml" style={monokai} id="html">
  {html}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

Here is demo repository: https://github.com/minhtranite/webpack-remove-snippet. Please run `start` and `start:prod` to see the difference result.

Comment: have you defined `form` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't defined the variable `form` as a result of which the build is failing. Or, language="html" is causing it to be parsed as html. language="text" will render it as text.

Comment: Yes. The snippet above just for example. In my app the build is success. Here is demo repository https://github.com/minhtranite/webpack-remove-snippet

Comment: @minh-tran language="text" fixed it for me.

Comment: Oh, Wow! Thank you so much :3